Reading Ethereum JSON-RPC data faster using web3.py
I know this kinda of question has been asked many times but none of them seem to meet my expectation. I am looking to extract total historical block transaction eth-values and also historical balances (or in-flow out-flows transaction values) for a number of addresses per block. The history length needs to be pretty long maybe a couple of years. The data does not necessarily need to be per block but let's say if it is hourly, it needs to get aggregated properly (so it does not miss any block values). For example this means when looking for eth-values per block it needs to get aggregated by sum to get the hourly values and if looking at balances of an address it needs to get aggregated by mean.
I have tried using web3 to get this data, does not matter what language I am using, Python or Rust, it is slow. I have even tried to parallelize with the maximum number of simultaneous connections that Alchemy allows (my RPC end point). It is very slow, this will require letting my computer stay on and run the scripts for days if not weeks. The number of values that needs to get extracted is in O(10^7) and maybe close to but less than 10^8 (if per block). Is there a better way of handling this? Is there a reasonably priced service that can offer such a thing?
I also discovered Google has made the blockchain data public through their BigQuery. Their data is amazing, I tried to query a few tables to just understand and see how they look like. I even put a limit of 10 on each query but after running a few of them, I apparently run out of the free quota (which seemed to be quite generous). So this suggests it will cost an arm and leg to pay for BigQuery to get something like this.

You cannot expect the world computer to run for free.
The preferred method is

Run a local JSON-RPC node for Ethereum

Query your node directly using JSON-RPC

Because the JSON-RPC is local, the latency is 0 and you can read as fast as your CPU can spin

Here is a Python library to do so

There are also specially indexer software to run locally e.g. TrueBlocks


If you cannot do this, you either need to pay for this

By paying someone (Google, Etherscan) for an API access

Luckily, there are some parties hosting free indexer APIs like indexed.xyz by Goldsky.

Ok the free indexer looks interesting, I'll take a look at that. Doesn't running eth node require holding a significant amount of eth?

No, running read only JSON-RPC node is the same as running any server-side software or long running process. You need to be connected to peer-to-peer network to download blocks only. Only validators that produce new blocks require staked ETH.
